# Abstract nonsingular curve birational to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to solve Exercise I.6.1 of Hartshorne, showing that a (quasi-projective) nonsingular rational curve $Y$ not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ is isomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^{1}$. To show this, by Theorem 6.7 of Hartshorne, we may assume that $Y$ is isomorphic to an abstract nonsingular curve $U$ of $C_{K(Y)}$. Then $U$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$, it suffices to show that $C_{K(Y)} \cong \mathbb{P}^{1}$, then $U$ is in an affine piece of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$.

However, what I stucked is to show $C_{K(Y)} \cong \mathbb{P}^{1}$. Since $C_{K(Y)} \setminus U$ is finite, thus by Theorem 6.8 we may extend a rational map $\phi:U \to \mathbb{P}^{1}$ to a morphism $\overline{\phi}:C_{K(Y)} \to \mathbb{P}^{1}$. However, I don't have any idea on extending the inverse of $\phi$ as a morphism and showing that those extended morphisms are actually isomorphism. Could you give me a hint to find them?

Comment: Hint: $Y$ birational to $\Bbb P^1$ means they have the same function field. I think you can do this more easily with corollary I.6.10, though.

Comment: @KReiser Do you mean that $K(Y) \cong K(\mathbb{P}^{1})$ implies $C_{K(Y)} \cong C_{K(\mathbb{P}^{1})}\cong \mathbb{P}^{1}$? If I tried to follow the proof of Theorem 6.9 explicitly on the case $C_{K(\mathbb{P}^{1})}$, what I've got is that $C_{K(\mathbb{P}^{1})}$ is isomorphic to a diagonal of $\mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{P}^{1}$, thus projection to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ induces isomorphism. Great, thank you very much!

Comment: @KReiser Also, if you don't mind, could you let me know how to use I.6.10 in this exercise? If we use the corollary, we may assume that $Y$ is isomorphic to an open subset nonsingular projective curve, say $Z$. Since $Y$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$, $Z$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$, but I don't know how to proceeds further without steps in my previous comment.

Comment: There is only one (up to isomorphism) nonsingular projective curve with a given function field, so that specific curve is the one the embedding lands in. In our case, that's $\Bbb P^1$.

Comment: @KReiser Wow great! How can I see the fact that there is only one nonsingular projective curve with a given function field?